JavaScript to queue submit request on client side and Trigger Submit Button at a Specified Time
I am working on developing a script that triggers the submit button at the end of a form at a specified time on client side. The goal of this test is to simulate a scenario where multiple users submit the same form simultaneously but with different details. Imagine 20 people in a room, all connected to the same network and each with their own device. They've all completed the application, and when someone says '1, 2, 3, go,' they all press the submit button at the exact same time.
I created the following script with the help of AI, but the problem is that it only refreshes the page instead of actually triggering the submit button. it stays on the same page after refresh and never redirect to the next page. pictures uploaded below.
let me tell you in advance that I am a beginner.
// Function to schedule a submit request
function scheduleSubmit() {
    // Set the specific time to submit
    const timeInput = "10:30 PM"; // Change this to your desired time

    // Validate the time input format
    const timePattern = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)$/;
    if (!timePattern.test(timeInput)) {
        console.error("Invalid time format. Please use HH:MM AM/PM format.");
        return;
    }

    const [time, period] = timeInput.split(' ');
    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':').map(Number);

    // Convert hours to 24-hour format
    if (period === 'PM' && hours < 12) {
        hours += 12;
    } else if (period === 'AM' && hours === 12) {
        hours = 0;
    }

    const now = new Date();
    const submitTime = new Date();

    // Set the submit time to today at the specified hours and minutes
    submitTime.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);

    // If the specified time is in the past, set it for tomorrow
    if (submitTime < now) {
        submitTime.setDate(submitTime.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Schedule the submit button click
    const delay = submitTime - now;
    setTimeout(() => {
        const submitButton = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-danger.btn-block.mt-3');
        if (submitButton) {
            submitButton.click();
            console.log(`Submit triggered at ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
        } else {
            console.error("Submit button not found.");
        }
    }, delay);

    console.log(`Submit scheduled for ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
}

// Call the scheduleSubmit function to start the process
scheduleSubmit();

here is an html code for submit button.
[<div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block  mt-3">Submit</button>
    </div>]

I have uploaded two pictures of the page. Page1 is about before applied the script and page two is about after applying a script.
Page1
Page2

Post code as a [mcve] and include HTML. There are many factors that depend on how the HTML is structured.

Are all your users in the same time zone?  Do any have their computers set to another time zone?  Submitting a form at a given time is different and routing to/display of a subsequent page is an entirely different matter for your server to manage/handle here.  IF one user has not fully filled the form are they to be prevented from submitting or just post the partially filled results?

FWIW it almost sounds like you want to perform some sort of an AJAX call to post data and then do something else - like a "form as a work flow" or some such.  I would perhaps be best to post the full page HTML if that is the case so we can best assist here - perhaps as a working snippet

@MarkSchultheiss Yes, all users are in the same time zone. Instead of the previous example, consider a scenario where 10 tabs in a browser are open, each with different form details filled in. The script will submit each form in its respective tab at a specific time as defined in the script. but the problem with the script is that it refreshes the page on the defined time and not redirecting to the next page which is about payment. the pictures i have uploaded may give some clue. thanks

As the HTML to the question wasn't provided I took the liberty of inventing my own. In the snippet below the data of the page's first <form> element will be evaluated (shown in a console.log() and sent to a remote server: https://dummyjson.com) at a given time (here: 19:45h local time):


// Function to schedule a submit request
function scheduleSubmit() {
const now=new Date(),
      submitTime=new Date();
submitTime.setHours(19);
submitTime.setMinutes(45);
submitTime.setSeconds(0);

// ======================
// temporary modification to demonstrate the delay on Stackoverflow:
// set target time to be 10 seconds in the future 
submitTime.setTime(now.getTime()+10000);
// ======================
if (submitTime < now) {
    submitTime.setDate(submitTime.getDate() + 1);
}

// Schedule the submit button click
const delay = submitTime - now;
setTimeout(() => {
  // extract all available input information 
  // from elements in the first user form of the page: 
  const d=Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.forms[0]));

  // do something with the entered form data, 
  // without actually submitting the form ... 
  fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/add",{method:"POST",headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},body: JSON.stringify({title:d})})
     .then(r=>r.json()).then(resp=>console.log("the server replied with:",resp));
  console.log(`Submit triggered at ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
 }, delay);
console.log(`Submit scheduled for ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
}

// Call the scheduleSubmit function to start the process
scheduleSubmit();
<form>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="Carsten"><br>
 <input type="text" name="favLang" value="JavaScript">
</form>



I modified OP's script to not operate on a particular <button> but instead to work with the <form> and its input elements. This way the form will not be submitted as such and a page reload is avoided. If you want to transfer the data to a server at the targeted time, you could use a fetch() call to establish this AJAX communication in the background. In the above snippet I sent the data to the publicly available API https://dummyjson.com .

The default behaviour of form in the browser is to trigger a page refresh after the form is submitted. If you want to disable the browser default for form submission, you should call event.preventDefault() in your scheduleSubmit() function and this will prevent your page from refreshing after the button is clicked.
function scheduleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
    // Set the specific time to submit
    const timeInput = "10:30 PM"; // Change this to your desired time

    // Validate the time input format
    const timePattern = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)$/;
    if (!timePattern.test(timeInput)) {
        console.error("Invalid time format. Please use HH:MM AM/PM format.");
        return;
    }

    const [time, period] = timeInput.split(' ');
    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':').map(Number);

    // Convert hours to 24-hour format
    if (period === 'PM' && hours < 12) {
        hours += 12;
    } else if (period === 'AM' && hours === 12) {
        hours = 0;
    }

    const now = new Date();
    const submitTime = new Date();

    // Set the submit time to today at the specified hours and minutes
    submitTime.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);

    // If the specified time is in the past, set it for tomorrow
    if (submitTime < now) {
        submitTime.setDate(submitTime.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Schedule the submit button click
    const delay = submitTime - now;
    setTimeout(() => {
        const submitButton = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-danger.btn-block.mt-3');
        if (submitButton) {
            submitButton.click();
            console.log(`Submit triggered at ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
        } else {
            console.error("Submit button not found.");
        }
    }, delay);

    console.log(`Submit scheduled for ${submitTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
}

// Call the scheduleSubmit function to start the process
scheduleSubmit();

It would have been very helpful if you posted your HTML document too but I hope this solves the refresh issue you're experiencing.

Thank you so much! After making a few tweaks, like removing the event parameter from the scheduleSubmit function and getting rid of the event.preventDefault() line since it’s no longer necessary, the script ran smoothly. However, it still just refreshes the page instead of redirecting to the next one after submission.

@Zmaray  You question says nothing about any "redirect to next one" or what "next one" is nor how your server handles the submit/redirect here.

@MarkSchultheiss you are right, sorry for that. the script just refreshes the page and not redirecting to the next page. i will add that to the question. thanks
